# Priority of Alphabetic order vs Lowest locant

Tags: nomenclature

I am confused about usage priority of lowest locant and alphabetical order rule(s)

For example :

3-ethyl 4,4 - dimethyl hexane

4-ethyl 3,3- dimethyl hexane

Which is considered correct (*or preferred*) **IUPAC** name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lowest locant has the priority over alphabetical order while numbering. But when writing name, we write according to alphabetical order. So 4-ethyl-3,3-dimethylhexane is the correct answer. One more thing, we don't consider the prefix 'di' on 'dimethyl' while deciding alphabetical order of the name.